# How to apply css to ngx-formly form feilds?

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I am new to formly. 
I am building a form using formly and each key I create is coming in a new line(column-wise) so I need some of them in a row so, how can I add CSS to my code and make it the way I want ??
I am not using bootstrap

Comment: I know that className can be added for a key but how can i use the class name and write css for it, I tried to write css  in the same component css file it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

whether use global css file or `::ng-deep` selector check the following example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnco5v

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `::ng-deep` since it's a bad practice, it's dangerous and soon it will be deprecated. I would go for the global css file, or even better, find the way to not add custom classes at all.